# Error: Too many SOQL queries: 101 on loop

Tags: trigger, class, query, error-messages

I am trying to solve the error that reads "`System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101`" on my code when trying to load some data. After going through system logs and searching them, I suppose the culprit would be the code below. Is there a way to Bulkify or avoid repetitive loop query on below code?
The query starting with "`Select BU_Manager__c ..`" seems to be the error-ing out.

```
public static void BUM_On_Sple(List<Sampling__c>sampling) {
    if(Trigger.isAfter) {
        for(Sampling__c sp: sampling) {

            id tempUser;
            Sampling__c s = new Sampling__c (id=sp.id); 

            List<Sampling__c> samplingUpdate = [select BU_Manager__c,BU_Manager1__c,BU_Manager2__c,BU_Manager3__c,BU_Manager4__c from Sampling__c where Id = :sp.id limit 1];
            if (!samplingUpdate.isEmpty()) {    
                Sampling__c samplingc = samplingUpdate[0];

                if(MapBUMgrs.containsKey(sp.Business_Unit__c+ sp.Product_Line__c + sp.Product_Family__c )) {

                    Business_Unit_Managers__c temps = MapBUMgrs.get(sp.Business_Unit__c+ sp.Product_Line__c + sp.Product_Family__c);
                    if(temps.BU_Manager__c!=null) 
                    tempUser = temps.BU_Manager__c;
                    else if(temps.BU_Manager1__c!=null)
                    tempUser=temps.BU_Manager__c;
                    else if(temps.BU_Manager2__c!=null)
                    tempUser=temps.BU_Manager__c;
                    else if(temps.BU_Manager3__c!=null)
                    tempUser=temps.BU_Manager__c;
                    else if(temps.BU_Manager4__c!=null)
                    tempUser=temps.BU_Manager__c;

                    samplingc.BU_Manager__c  =(temps.BU_Manager__c!=null  ? temps.BU_Manager__c :tempUser);
                    samplingc.BU_Manager1__c =(temps.BU_Manager1__c!=null ? temps.BU_Manager1__c :tempUser);
                    samplingc.BU_Manager2__c =(temps.BU_Manager2__c!=null ? temps.BU_Manager2__c :tempUser);
                    samplingc.BU_Manager3__c =(temps.BU_Manager3__c!=null ? temps.BU_Manager3__c :tempUser);
                    samplingc.BU_Manager4__c =(temps.BU_Manager4__c!=null ? temps.BU_Manager4__c :tempUser);
                    try {
                        update samplingc;
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {
                         System.Debug('Exception : Update of this operation failed ' + e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the below statement (Line 8) which is inside a **loop**

```
        List<Sampling__c> samplingUpdate = [select BU_Manager__c,BU_Manager1__c,BU_Manager2__c,BU_Manager3__c,BU_Manager4__c from Sampling__c where Id = :sp.id limit 1];
```

Better way is to collect all the Sampling__c Ids in a List and use it in SOQL

```
   List<Id> samplingIds = new List<Id>();

    for(Sampling__c sp: sampling) {
            samplingIds.add(sp.Id);
    }

    List<Sampling__c> samplingUpdates = [select BU_Manager__c,BU_Manager1__c,BU_Manager2__c,BU_Manager3__c,BU_Manager4__c from Sampling__c where Id in :samplingIds];

    for(Sampling__c samplingUpdate:samplingUpdates) {

        // REST OF THE CODE WILL BE SAME
    }
```

Instead of doing **where Id=sp.Id limit 1**, its better to use **where Id in :samplingIds** which makes the code much cleaner as well as reduces the unnecessary SOQL executions

**Reference**:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice:_Avoid_SOQL_Queries_Inside_FOR_Loops

Comment: Thank you. Now based on new code, I get following errror  `Expression must be a list type: Sampling__c` <br/> 
 `List<Id> samplingIds = new List<Id>();
 for(Sampling__c sp: sampling) {
   samplingIds.add(sp.Id);
 }       
 List<Sampling__c> samplingUpdates = [select BU_Manager__c,BU_Manager1__c,BU_Manager2__c,BU_Manager3__c,BU_Manager4__c, Business_Unit__c, Product_Line__c, Product_Family__c  from Sampling__c where Id in :samplingIds];
 for(Sampling__c samplingUpdate:samplingUpdates) {
  id tempUser;
  if (!samplingUpdate.isEmpty()) {
   Sampling__c samplingc = samplingUpdate[0]; `

Comment: Gopi remove the check if (!samplingUpdate.isEmpty()) {    
                Sampling__c samplingc = samplingUpdate[0]; and let samplingc=sampingUpdate.  We don't need this check since we no more send a List, but Sampling__c record directly. So you can remove isEmpty() check and getting the first record from List and assiging the Sampling record step

Comment: I removed the isEmpty() check and changed the next code to `samplingc = samplingUpdate;` . But I have code to assignment and update code don't work. <br/> samplingc.BU_Manager__c  =(temps.BU_Manager__c!=null  ? temps.BU_Manager__c :tempUser); update samplingc;  <br/> Also getting the following error `Compile Error: Variable does not exist: samplingc`

Comment: Hey I meant  Sampling__c samplingc = samplingUpdate, and not literally to use my pseudo code

Comment: Awesome....That worked!!

Comment: Great, hope that helps :)